# Woocommerce payment gateway request

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In which php script in woocommerce do I add my payment gateway request code? I was told to put it in checkout page where ORDER NOW button exists. But am unable to find the exact PHP..Please help me find the exact php script.

Answer (score 1):

Don't modify WooCommerce core directly.
You should use the actions and filters to extend WooCommerce's functionality.

Please refter to https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/payment-gateway-api/ for some examples.